# How to drop high voltage DC with resistors only

Tags: voltage

Last year I made an electronics device that would drop high voltages DC to 24VDC from 50VDC, 75VDC and, 120VDC.

These voltages drops were selected by using a 3 position, 12 terminal, no 0 position Cam Switch.

These voltage changes were made using resistors only (1 resistor per voltage change).

The reason I am asking for help is because, I suffer from a head injury while serving in the US Army that effects my memory. I have video of my electronics device working but I failed to make notes on how I wired my resistors. I used single resistors for my three voltage changes and somehow or another, it worked perfectly.

I have recently tried to duplicate my work from last year but, I am having no success. I wish you guys could see my one year old video so that you could figure out what made my device work. I thought that I wired my resistors in series with my load but, that doesn't seem to work now.

Comment: I can't make any promises (leaving right now), but if you upload that video somewhere and link to it from here, others might have a look. Your question is well-written and seems to be based on a reasonable design, so chances are good you'll find someone able to help!

Comment: If you use only one resistor, the voltage will depend on the load. More load = more voltage drop. With two resistors you can make a "voltage divider".

Comment: Is it the same load?